# Versioning for solo projects

Tags: version-control

I have been searching both google and other SO questions but none really describe my situation. 
I often create a copy of a project when I have a major feature working, so that I don't destroy it when I keep coding. Currently I am just copying the project in eclipse and renaming it to something like "MyProject2.0". This leaves my workspace VERY cluttered though.

[image: workspace]

Those are not huge upgrades, for normal versioning this is x.0.z, x.1.z, x.2.z at best. Should I just use Git or something similar? I am looking for a way to keep the old code(easily at hand) but also not clutter up my workspace like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any version control system will help. I've used rcs, cvs, svn and git along the way, any of them will do the trick for you. Choosing a revision control system, especially if you are a soloist is personal choice. You may want to consider git, as it is quite a good tool for what you are describing.  GIT is well described on the git site with practical examples.  Using it will surely get rid of your clutter. You should specifically read up on the [git workflow](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows)  that describes how to work with branches in a git controlled project. Also look at "stashing" in git, you'll see what I mean about git being nice for solo projects.

Comment: I've played around a bit with Git now. Doesn't this mean that I still need to manually copy the files from my workspace to my Git folder? Or would I just "make" my workspace(or my individual Projects in Eclipse?) the Git folder?

Comment: you can make your folder into the git folder ... or you can create a separate space for the git repos and just check out the work environment separately.  Git is flexible enough to do both and you can always change your mind :)  ... Suggest that you start with one project committed to git in the same directory as you are working in; and play with it.  Read up on it at git.org they have good tutorials there showing various scenarios.

Comment: I ended up accepting this answer, simply because I ended up using Git. Other VCS will obviously work aswell!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you definitely should. Use Subversion, Git, Mercurial, CVS ... whatever you feel fine working with. Even for solo projects version control software is a *huge* help in my experience.